# Which airlines fly from Ulaanbaatar / Ulan Bator?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, london, mongolia, ulan-bator

Looking at getting back to London from Ulaanbaatar (Ulan Bator), Mongolia in mid August, and trying to reduce the price.  What airlines or crazy routes might exist?

Currently have found Aeroflot, Mongolian Airlines, Korean Air, and Air China - although obviously some of those are flying in the wrong direction.  Aeroflot seems to have the best price most days, although I can't find a supposed ULN to Berlin Mongolian Airlines flight...

Comment: For example, just found Air China to Bangkok, and then Jet Airways to London.  It's slow but quite comparable price-wise.  Price is the biggest factor for me here.

Comment: I've become a huge fan of Korean Air. I always seem to get a seat at a very good price even when booking very late. Plus the service is excellent. Air China will probably be a few dollars cheaper though. As for the others I don't know what kind of glue they stick the wings on with (-;

Comment: And then would you believe, Aeroflot go and drop their prices 10%.  Booked! Thanks :)

Comment: You might have some luck offering a bounty on [FlightFox](http://flightfox.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia is a great source for these type of questions, I always use it as a primary source to find which airlines fly to a specific destination. This enables me to narrow the search for an interesting fare.

To answer this question I have entered "Wikipedia Ulaanbaatar Airport" in Google and I was directed to this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinggis_Khaan_International_Airport) entry:

- Aero Mongolia:   Altai, Bayankhongor, Choibalsan, Donoi, Hohhot, Hovd, Irkutsk, Ölgii, Oyutolgoi, Ovoot, Ulaangom, Urumqi
- Aeroflot:    Moscow-Sheremetyevo
- Air China:   Beijing-Capital
- Eznis Airways:   Bayankhongor, Choibalsan, Dalanzadgad, Khovd, Khuvsgul,Ulaangom, Bayan Ulgii, Zavkhan, Oyutolgoi, Ovoot, Hailaar, Ulan-Ude
- Korean Air:  Seoul-Incheon
- MIAT Mongolian Airlines: Beijing-Capital, Berlin-Tegel, Hong Kong, Moscow-Sheremetyevo, Seoul-Incheon, Tokyo-Narita **Seasonal** Osaka-Kansai, Tokyo-Haneda
- Tianjin Airlines:    Hohhot, Tianjin
- Ural Airlines: Yekaterinburg, Sanya

Answer (score 3):

According my search, the Aeroflot has the cheapest price (near $900) for this trip, with 1 stop in [Sheremetyevo (SVO)](http://svo.aero/en/):

- [15 August](http://www.anywayanyday.com/avia/offers/?RequestId=73bcd92c-99bd-4306-8969-66d7814caf19&DestStep=1&Currency=USD), $973
- [17 August](http://www.anywayanyday.com/avia/searching/?RequestId=e2b3b0c4-d470-4983-bab7-0ab27a9e9cc0), $877
- [17 August](http://sindbad.ru/ru/flight/results/ULNLHR20110817100E0), $896

And I didn't find any flights in mid August for Air China.

Comment: Just found Air China to PEK for $222 on 14th, then $611 Uzbek air  to LON on the 16th. Total $833.  Really roundabout way, but I do love flying...still looking ;)

Comment: @Mark Mayo What site and what date?

Comment: Curses, you need a Chinese visa for more than 12 hours of transit...

Comment: kayak.co.uk, I use.

Comment: -1 since the answer will not be valid in a month.

Comment: @Andra Did you read the question? We are searching for mid August, not just the list of companies.

Comment: Yes, but it's still helpful as I can check their websites :)

Comment: How will this answer help future visitors?

Comment: @todofixthis This question was very time-specific, as my answer is.

Comment: @todofixthis Well, it will point them to Aeroflot and give them some idea of what to expect. How could any list of airlines or any price comparison be valid forever? Is anything missing in the answer? Wouldn't saying an airline flies this route and is the cheapest be the only possible answer to the question? How, then, could *adding* something make the answer *less* useful, even if the prices are not current anymore?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2013, Turkish Airlines started flying to Ulan Bator directly from Istanbul, or on some days via Bishkek. Depending on the exact days of travel, that might be the cheapest connection from Europe.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Care to provide some references for your claims?

Comment: Sure, I generally use momondo for finding the most suitable connections, it works really well for Helsinki. For example I tried 12-19 February:

http://www.momondo.com/flightsearch/?Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=HEL&SD0=ULN&SDP0=12-02-2015&SO1=ULN&SD1=HEL&SDP1=19-02-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false#Search=true&TripType=2&SegNo=2&SO0=HEL&SD0=ULN&SDP0=12-02-2015&SO1=ULN&SD1=HEL&SDP1=19-02-2015&AD=1&TK=ECO&DO=false&NA=false

It says 595 euro from Helsinki to Mongolia and back with Turkish Airlines, and the cheapest tickets with any other airlines cost 811 euro on the same days.