# Do our Indian flights go to Bangkok?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, bangkok, new-delhi

I am travelling on an international flight for the first time. I am staying in New Delhi and would like to travel to Bangkok.

Do Indian flights go to Bangkok? And how or where will I get the timings? Can I book this myself or do I need to use an Agent?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question "Do Indian flights go to Bangkok?" Are you basically asking what kind of flight connections are available from New Delhi to Bangkok (airlines & timetables)?

Comment: Hi Aakesh, welcome to Travel.SE. Unfortunately, this question is WAY too basic to be covered on this site. A simple web search will point you to numerous online booking sites as well as real-world travel agents with whom you can book flights, find out schedules, etc.

Comment: How did this question get "migrated" and then closed. Do (or should) you need moderator permission to "migrate" a question?

Comment: @TomAu indeed and it is also very strange that this question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/which-airlines-fly-from-ulaanbaatar didn't get closed. The similarity between these two are obvious.

Comment: I think this question is worse. It doesn't mention an airport or an airline or whether only Indian airlines are considered like it implies. Also it includes multiple questions, the one about booking is as unanswerable as the one about routes. And the OP is an anonymous user so I'm not sure they'll even get the feedback in these comments to be able the improve the question. If you feel you know what is really being asked feel free to edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @TomAu: This question was initially asked on WebApps.SE, where it wasn't a fit for their site. Their mods migrated it to our site as they believed it to be the best match. On our site here, moderators take a look at questions and see what's on/off-topic. The two incidents are separate.

Comment: @Andra: The question on Ulaan Bataar was specific: it mentioned what criteria was being looked for flights and it is admittedly a niche route to fly on. This, here, is more of a question asking whether travel agents exist or how to even search for flights online - which a trivial 'flights to Bangkok' web search can answer. Furthermore, it's from an anonymous user and thus a request to edit the question cannot be flagged via SE's global inbox. Similarly, if someone asked a question tomorrow 'Are there any flights from London to New York? How do I find them?', it'll be closed as trivial too.

Comment: The question was migrated because of my answer for the WebApps-mods request. I thought that this question can be some advertizing from WebApps site. I hope the @aakesh adhikari will edit his question so it can fit in our site.